# Splitting array into groups using typescript/javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript

I have this:

```
    products = [
       {
         'id': 1
         'name: 'test'
       },
       {
         'id': 2
         'name: 'test'
       },
       {
         'id': 3
         'name: 'test'
       }
       ... etc, etc
    ]
```

I need to restructure it to this:

```
    products = [
       row1: [
        {
         'id': 1
         'name: 'test'
        },
        {
         'id': 2
         'name: 'test'
        },
        {
         'id': 3
         'name: 'test'
        },
        {
         'id': 4
         'name: 'test'
        }
       ]
    row2: [
       {
         'id': 5
         'name: 'test'
        },
        {
         'id': 6
         'name: 'test'
        },
        {
         'id': 7
         'name: 'test'
        },
        {
         'id': 8
         'name: 'test'
        }
       ]
       row3: [.. etc, etc
    ]
```

the hard part is that the number of objects in each group is set using a variable (in this example the variable would be 4).

How can I achieve this using Typescript/Javascript? Its driving me mad!

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split array into chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried this but i need the nested arrays to have names (row1, row2, etc). How can I add the array names?

Comment: You would need an object for that, I added an answer on how you can implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

You can run a .reduce() method on your products array, like so:

```js
var products = [
   { 'id': 1, name: 'test' },
   { 'id': 2, name: 'test' },
   { 'id': 3, name: 'test' },
   { 'id': 4, name: 'test' },
   { 'id': 5, name: 'test'  },
   { 'id': 6, name: 'test' }
]

var numberOfObjects = 4 // <-- decides number of objects in each group

var groupedProducts = products.reduce((acc, elem, index) => {
  var rowNum = Math.floor(index/numberOfObjects) + 1
  acc[`row${rowNum}`] = acc[`row${rowNum}`] || []
  acc[`row${rowNum}`].push(elem)
  return acc
}, {})

console.log(groupedProducts)
```

Comment: `reduce()` would be more useful if the chunking was based on the value of the individual items. Since it's not, there's no need to iterate over each item, repeatedly calculating `rowNum`, testing for the row's existence (or creating it), or pushing individual items one at a time. This solution functions but it suffers from some of the same inefficiencies as the other array-iteration-method solutions.

Answer (score 8):

### Option A: Custom Chunking/Translation Method

Given that you'd like to break the array into chunks **without regard for item content**, I'd suggest a simple loop to step through the array by chunk-size, slicing subsets as we go:

```js
function chunk(array, chunkSize) { 
  // Create a plain object for housing our named properties: row1, row2, ...rowN
  const output = {}, 
  // Cache array.length
  arrayLength = array.length;
  // Loop variables
  let arrayIndex = 0, chunkOrdinal = 1;
  // Loop over chunks
  while (arrayIndex < arrayLength) {
    // Use slice() to get a chunk. Note the incrementing/assignment operations.
    output[`row${chunkOrdinal++}`] = array.slice(arrayIndex, arrayIndex += chunkSize);
  }
  return output;
}
// Testing with a simplified demo array
console.table(chunk([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 4));
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script><style>.as-console-wrapper{display:block}</style><script>console.config({timeStamps:false,maximize:true})</script>
```

This has a few advantages over some of the `reduce()` and `Object.groupBy()` suggestions. This one:

- Steps by chunk-size rather than 1; so, it performs far fewer iterations.
- Has no need for repeated, comparative logic or calculations (no division or flooring) for every index. The item content is irrelevant; so, we don't bother processing each individual item.
- Defines each `rowN` property *once* and never has to check whether it already exists.
- Uses the native `Array.prototype.slice()` method to select our subsets rather than pushing individual items one at a time.

### Option B: Pre-chunk and Reduce

Alternatively, you could pre-chunk the array using a more generic (reusable?) method and then use `Array.prototype.reduce()` on the resultant, shorter, two-dimensional array. This mitigates many of the weaknesses of using reduce on its own and actually becomes faster than Option A at certain thresholds of input array length and chunk size:

```js
function generateChunks(array, size) {
  // Cache array.length
  const length = array.length;
  // Pre-size output array so we don't have to push/resize
  const output = new Array(Math.ceil(length / size));
  // Loop variables
  let seekIndex = 0, outputIndex = 0;
  // Loop over chunks
  while (seekIndex < length) {
    // Use slice() to get a chunk. Note the incrementing/assignment operations.
    output[outputIndex++] = array.slice(seekIndex, seekIndex += size);
  }
  // Return our chunks
  return output;
}

console.table(
  // Pre-chunk
  generateChunks([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 4)
    // Reduce to translate into the desired object
    .reduce((output, chunk, index) => {
      output[`row${index + 1}`] = chunk;
      return output;
    },{})
);
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script><style>.as-console-wrapper{display:block}</style><script>console.config({timeStamps:false,maximize:true})</script>
```

Either of these methods, A or B, should be ~10x faster than [the accepted reduce() answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60014607) and [the new Object.groupBy() answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77061673/621962), with the advantage scaling up (by orders of magnitude) as the input array length and/or chunk size increases... particularly as chunk-size increases relative to input length.
Here's a [jsbench](https://jsbench.me/xvkv1dmqul/1) comparing these options using a chunk size of `10` and an input length of `99`.

JavaScript engines are getting smarter all the time and it's likely their developers will continue to find new ways to optimize your loops, regardless of your preferred construct. So, your mileage may vary. Feel free to fork the test to try different input data or chunk sizes.

Answer (score 0):

There's an experimental implementation for `Object.groupBy` that's supported in pre-release versions of most browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/groupBy

Hopefully this will be the go-to way to solve this in the future.

Example usage (untested and shouldn't work unless using a prelease version...):

```js
  const products = [
       {
         'id': 1,
         'name': 'test1'
       },
       {
         'id': 2,
         'name': 'test2'
       },
       {
         'id': 3,
         'name': 'test3'
       },
       {
         'id': 4,
         'name': 'test4'
       },
       {
         'id': 5,
         'name': 'test5'
       },
    ]
    
const columnsPerRow = 3;    

const table = Object.groupBy(products,(p,index)=>{
  return `row${Math.floor(index/columnsPerRow)}`
  })
  
console.log(table)
```

Comment: `Object.groupBy()` is a great tool for when you need to group based on item content! Unfortunately, it's still reliant on generating a key per item, which is wasteful given the OP's item-agnostic requirements.  It also performs poorly for this case, i.e.: about on par with `reduce()`: https://jsbench.me/xvkv1dmqul/1.

Comment: It performs fantastically - depending on how you measure performance ;). For me, this approach is the quickest and easiest to interpret as a developer. It's essentially a special syntax for a common use case of reduce. Sure, it's going to be slower in execution - but that's rarely at issue for most use cases. If you really want fast execution - using splice is going to get a 100x speedup over slice in your option A.

Comment: Performance is certainly relative; I bring it up when execution times differ in orders of magnitude. If you could demonstrate your `splice()` method as a new test case in the benchmark, a 100x gain would certainly be valuable! That said, I'm skeptical that introducing iterative input array mutation would improve performance and not impact results. A naïve swap between `slice()` and `splice()` definitely affects the output; so, I'd like to compare with your version.

Comment: https://jsbench.me/9vlmp8toh9/1

Copying data is where the biggest performance hit is going to be, if you're able to mutate the array then you can really save some time. If you can't mutate or aren't needing to optimize runtime performance, then the technique that is easiest to read (and update if needed) is the better option - a matter of personal taste and codebase convention. I think `Object.groupBy` is my favorite (at least at the moment!).

Comment: Okay, I see what happened. Most of your iterations were processing a 0-length array since you were modifying the shared setup input array. Just slap a `console.log(input.length)` in there to see. I've modified the bench (https://jsbench.me/5jlmpciv91/1)  to prevent this from happening (and to remove the now-redundant shallow-copy test) and results are now in line with what I'd expect: `splice()` performs much better than `reduce()` and `Object.groupBy()` but worse than `slice()`, presumably because `slice()` doesn't modify the input array.

Comment: You are correct, thanks for the update! I was thinking splice would just change start/end pointers of the modified array and the returned array would just adopt start/end pointers of the spliced elements. Something tells me there's more overhead than that (creating a new array anyway and moving data around in the old array). This would make slice more efficient than splice as you have pointed out.

Comment: Based on the initial performance claim, I suspected something similar; but the [spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.splice) remaps individual indices. Additionally, given that `splice()` can remove/inject items anywhere in the array, an optimization for lead segment removal seems unlikely -particularly since [`shift()`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.shift) has no such an optimization and _all_ that does is remove the first item and shift down. Who knows what the vendors do in native space, though.

Answer (score -1):

Lodash `groupBy` is handy.
It takes an array, and an iterator function and groups the entries in the array accordingly.
The grouping logic can easily be done by counting the index for each iteration, and increment the group count on when the modulo (remainder) operator returns zero.

Using your example:

```js
const { groupBy } = require("lodash");

const products = [
  { id: "1", name: "test" },
  { id: "2", name: "test" },
  { id: "3", name: "test" },
  { id: "4", name: "test" },
  { id: "5", name: "test" },
  { id: "6", name: "test" },
  { id: "7", name: "test" },
  { id: "8", name: "test" },
];
const myGroupingFunction = (val) => {
  ++index;
  const groupLabel = "row" + groupCount;
  if (index % groupSize === 0) {
    ++groupCount;
  }
  return groupLabel;
};

const groupSize = 2;
let groupCount = 1;
let index = 0;
const groupedEntries = groupBy(products, myGroupingFunction);

console.log("GroupedEntries: ", groupedEntries);


// GroupedEntries:  {
//  row1: [ { id: '1', name: 'test' }, { id: '2', name: 'test' } ],
//  row2: [ { id: '3', name: 'test' }, { id: '4', name: 'test' } ],
//  row3: [ { id: '5', name: 'test' }, { id: '6', name: 'test' } ],
//  row4: [ { id: '7', name: 'test' }, { id: '8', name: 'test' } ]
//}
```

This will iterate through a list, group the entries in equally sized groups according to the `groupSize` variable, in the order they appear in the list.

If you want, you can also calculate the group number based on object values in the list. I'm incrementing an index instead.

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy

Answer (score -2):

This should return exactly what you are looking for:

```
const filteredProducts = {}
products.map((product, i) => {
  const row = `row${Math.floor(i / 4) + 1}`
  if (!filteredProducts[row]) filteredProducts[row] = []
  return filteredProducts[row].push(product)
})
```

Comment: Likely because it doesn't come with any explanation, or in-line comments to describe the code. Usually people want to understand how you solved the problem, or the limitations of your solution. Also- you used the `map` method needlessly if you're not going to use the returned value. You might as well just have used `forEach`, or the reduce function described in a different answer.